# MDX: What is the difference of these both queries

Tags: mdx

`MDX`: What is the difference of these queries, I'm using adventure works database.

```
SELECT 
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY ([Product].[Category].[Category] ,
          [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year])ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]

GO

SELECT 
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY ([Product].[Category].[Category] *
          [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year])ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two scripts are the same.

This is effectively putting a set of tuples on the rows - you've definied the tuple explicitly using the braces `(...)`

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    (  //<<start of tuple
      [Product].[Category].[Category]
     ,[Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year]
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

The second script is a cross join via the star operator `*`:

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Product].[Category].[Category] * [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year] ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

When you action a `crossjoin` it returns a set of tuples - so you end up with the same cell set.

You could write crossjoin instead of using the star - although the star is the most used notation in modern mdx scripts:

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    CrossJoin
    (
      [Product].[Category].[Category]
     ,[Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year]
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```